# Add a button in Leaflet Popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am working on a project using React JS and Leaflet.
I am trying to call a function using a button inside a leaflet popup.

A and B are the start and end coordinates.

```
L.polyline([A, B]).addTo(this.state.map).bindPopup('<button onclick="print()">Print</button>')

print = () => {
      // Add some logic here 
      console.log("Prints")
}
```

The popup is added with the button but function print isn't being called when the button is clicked.
The error received is `Uncaught ReferenceError: print is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery like this,

```
$('button').click(function(){
});
```

define whatever you want that function to do.

Comment: I tried the above but it didn't work. And, I found other answers on Stackoverflow suggesting to avoid using jQuery and ReactJS together.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [React Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/).
You can create Popups like Components, so you only have to put the button component inside the [Popup](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#popup) component.

Example:

```
        <Popup position={positionPopup}>
            <Button label="Example" className="p-button-rounded" onClick={() => { console.log("Button pressed")}}
             />
        </Popup>
```

You have an example of using Marker and PopUp components [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker/).